# JPA - Erro de registro não encontrado logo após a inserção do mesmo

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jpa-2.0

Uma dúvida em relação a procedimentos do JPA, por conta de um erro que aconteceu e não estou conseguindo entender.

Estou cuidando de uma parte do sistema que alimenta uma tabela de pedidos de cartão. Ele busca se o usuário que o pedido faz referência possui o cartão, e ele insere antes de inserir na tabela de créditos. Porém ele dá um erro de chave-pai não encontrada, mesmo inserindo antes na tabela de cartão.

Abaixo o que é apresentado no console:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-24 16:22:50.166--ClientSession(1319007734)--Connection(2018078818)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--INSERT INTO CARTAO (CD_CARTAO, |demais campos|) VALUES (?, |demais campos|)
    bind => [10905487, |demais campos|]
[EL Finest]: query: 2015-04-24 16:22:50.17--UnitOfWork(459973678)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query UpdateObjectQuery(br.com.virtus.sgc.model.Pedido@21144823)
[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-24 16:22:50.171--ClientSession(1319007734)--Connection(2018078818)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--UPDATE PEDIDO SET CD_FASE_ATUAL = ? WHERE (CD_PEDIDO = ?)
    bind => [6, 22557]
[EL Finest]: query: 2015-04-24 16:22:50.174--UnitOfWork(459973678)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(br.com.virtus.sgc.model.Cardcredito@6e8d1800)
[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-24 16:22:50.175--ClientSession(1319007734)--Connection(2018078818)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--INSERT INTO CARDCREDITO (ID_CARDCREDITO,  VL_CREDITO, CD_CARTAO, CD_PEDIDO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [1721388, 356, 10905487, 22557]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-24 16:22:50.182--ClientSession(1319007734)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
[EL Warning]: 2015-04-24 16:22:50.188--UnitOfWork(459973678)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02291: restrição de integridade (SGCMASTER.RI_CARDCREDITO) violada - chave-pai não localizada
```

No console mostra o mesmo número de cartão: **10905487**. Este ID é gerado por uma Sequence do Oracle.

E claro, o código:

```
public void processar(){
        BigDecimal icCardcredito;
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            List<Pedido> lstAProcessar  = this.listagemPedidosAProcessar();
            TipoFasePedido proc         = new TipoFasePedidoImpl().pesquisarPorId(Long.valueOf(qryParam.pesquisarPorNmChave("CD_FASE_PEDIDO_PROCESSADO").getNmValor()));
            HistoricoPedido histPed     = new HistoricoPedido();            
            for(Pedido ped:lstAProcessar){
                ped.setCardcreditos(new ArrayList<Cardcredito>());
                icCardcredito = BigDecimal.ONE;
                List<PedidoDetalhe> infoPedido = this.listaValores(ped);
                for (PedidoDetalhe info: infoPedido){
                    Produto prod = ped.getProduto();
                    Cliente clie = ped.getCliente();
                    String  cpf  = info.getCdCpf();
                    Cartao  card = new Cartao(); 
                    card         =  this.pegaCartao(cpf, clie, prod);//Aqui ele busca o cartão
                    boolean tem  = (card instanceof Cartao);
                    if (!(tem)){
                        card = novoCartao(info);
                        em.persist(card);
                    }
                    Cardcredito itemCred = new Cardcredito();
                    itemCred.setCartao(card);
                    itemCred.setVlCredito(info.getVlCredito());
                    ped.addCardcredito(itemCred);
                    em.merge(ped);
                    icCardcredito.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
                }
                histPed = new HistoricoPedido();

                histPed.setTipoFasePedido(proc);
                histPed.setDtFasePedido(new Date());
                histPed.setNmOperador(qryUtils.nmUsuarioSistema());

                ped.setTipoFasePedido(proc);
                ped.addHistoricoPedido(histPed);

                em.merge(ped);                      
            }       
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            System.out.println("---ERRO!----" + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Minha dúvida é:

Qual a explicação disto acontecer? 
Tem algo a ver com o `cascadeType` entre as tabelas?

Testei com `ALL` e `PERSIST` e em ambas deram este erro.

Valeu!

[**Atualizando**]

Estava verificando a base e me dei conta que as triggers estavam ativas (para lidar com as *sequences*, estou usando o `@GeneratedValue` e `@SequenceGenerator` no modelo.) Inativei e pelo visto foi isso.

Mas ainda assim aconteceu algo curioso.

A tabela de cartão possui uma tabela relacionada de histórico. Ela é alimentada durante o processo, e depois de ter desativado as *triggers*, estava dando erro exatamente nela (de chave pai não encontrada). Tirei a informação `TIMESTAMP` da data e coloquei `DATE` e passou por esta etapa normalmente.

Qual relação que existe entre os campos de data e uma PK?

Comment: Provavelmente você está com o "classico" problema de "read commited". Para não correr risco de eu dar um palpite  errado, tente commitar a primeira transacao e depois, faça a pesquisa normalmente e veja se o registro é encontrado e poste aqui o resultado.

Comment: pergunta boba, tá rolando commit na transação?

Comment: Não... Como tinha mencionado acima, era uma `Trigger Before Insert` do Oracle que chamava a Sequence. Ao desativar, deixando a `sequence` mencionada na classe, deu tudo certo.

Comment: Thiago, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Seria interessante você postar sua solução como resposta a sua própria pergunta, pois isso facilita quem visitar o site entender como resolver o problema. Quanto à sua outra pergunta sobre triggers, seria melhor postar uma pergunta separada, pois aqui ela vai receber pouca ou nenhuma atenção, além de fugir do tópico original. Abraço!

Comment: @utluiz A pergunta separada eu já tenho a solução também. Devo colocar a pergunta E a solução ou no Stack Overflow tem um espaço já destinado para isto?

Comment: Tiago, pelo visto você achou o local das respostas. Sempre que encontrar a solução para o seu próprio problema não exite em postar. Não temos problemas com isso, muito pelo contrário, o importante é compartilhar o conhecimento. Só não faça isso caso a solução não seja uma resposta de verdade, tipo "desisti e fiz outra coisa". Abraço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conferindo o banco de dados e notei que as triggers estavam ativas. Assim como o @GeneratedValue e @SequenceGenerator estavam sendo utilizados na classe.

Logo, o id era atualizado dentro da classe, mas era alterado na base pela trigger, que chamava novamente a sequence.

Inativei a trigger, (assim a sequence é atualizada somente de uma maneira, e somente uma vez) e deu tudo certo.